# What are Catalyst "challenge setting" challenges for?

Tags: catalyst

I have a solution idea that can be solved by Cardano and couldn't find the right category for it.  I want to put it in the "challenge setting" challenge.

Do "challenge setting" challenges have limits on what can be proposed?

Comment: What do you mean by "community challenges"? Are you referring to the "Challenge setting"?

Comment: Thanks, edited for clarity and correct terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "challenge setting" challenge is how the Catalyst community chooses the themes and funding for *some* of the Catalyst challenges following the next six-week cycle.

They are significantly different than most other challenges.

- No reward is given to proposers
- Proposals suggest new challenges
- They do not contains proposals or solutions
- Funds requested become the budget of the challenge
- The outcome takes 3+ months to complete

There is a long lead time on funds proposed in the challenge budget being delivered to the proposals that win in the resulting challenge.  If the challenge has a timeliness component (e.g. a "Women" theme to coincide with = International Women's day) it is best to propose it about 90 days in advance.